# Using an Air as an iPod dock for extra headphone volume

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, ipod-classic

I have an iPod Classic 160GB synced with iTunes in Windows on a desktop computer.

Volume from the iPod through headphones is too soft. When I'm away from the desktop, is it possible to connect the iPod to my MacBook Air to listen to content through the Air as if it were a docking station? I could use headphones on the Air.

Comment: Why is the volume from the iPod through its headphones too soft?  I have had similar trouble.

Comment: Volume through earphones or ear-pods is fine. I think the iPod does not have enough power to drive headphones.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'd suggest changing the question title to something like "Using an Air as an iPod dock for extra power to drive headphones".

Answer (score 1):

Try using a line-in cable and plug it into the headphone/microphone jack. This Apple support article could have your answer: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201929